# How to iterate Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>() in a jsp page using JSTL

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, hashmap, jstl

I add two list into one  Map map = new HashMap(). I want to get values from that in a jsp page using JSTL
My contriller is

```
     @RequestMapping("/addprogram")
 public ModelAndView thematicday()

  {
     Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>(); 
     try{
        List<Themes> theme=dataServices.getTheme();
        List<String> themeday=dataServices.getThematicDate();

         map.put("theme", theme);
         map.put("themeday", themeday);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     return new ModelAndView("thematicday","map",map);
  }
```

I exctract first list

```
   <c:forEach var="events" items="${map.theme}">
                            <option value="${events.themeid}">${events.themename}</option>
```

But I dont know how to exctract values from String list

second list in daoImpl

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<String> getDate() {
     List<ThematicDay> Themedate = null;
    session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx=session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery( "select a.themedate,a.thematicdayid from tableone a where a.thematicdayid in(SELECT thematicdayid FROM tabetwo GROUP BY thematicdayid HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)");
    List<Object> result = (List<Object>) query.list();

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object object : result) {
        strings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n *&*&*&* "+strings);
    for(int i=0; i<strings.size(); i++){
        String stringArray = strings.get(i);
        System.out.println("\n\n *&*&*&* "+stringArray);


    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    return strings;
}
```

I use this code to get that list

```
<c:forEach var="Date" items="${map}">
                     <c:if test="${Date.key == 'themeday'}">
                    <div class="bottom-article">
                        <ul class="meta-post">
                            <li><a href="#" class="tl_1"> ${Date.value[0]} </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="tl_2">${Date.value[1]} </a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                        </c:if>
                        </c:forEach>
```

But get the result like this

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@762b0f
[Ljava.lang.Object;@4f983
```

Comment: you need to observe the `List<Object>` you are getting , an dthen populate `List<String>`, do not use `object.toString()`, iterate `List<Object>` and get value of `themedate` and fill the `List<String>`

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
<c:forEach var="themedays" items="${map.themeday}">
     <c:foreach var="theme" items="${themedays}">
       <b> ${theme} </b>
    </c:foreach>
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: Sorry I get the result
"themedays themedays". Actually I need to get the result 
01/14/2015 DAY1007
02/14/2015 DAY1008

Comment: get values  [Ljava.lang.Object;@a3e5fc [Ljava.lang.Object;@502bb9. Not the exact values.

Comment: @PriyankaShaju just observed, you are doing `object.toString()`, what object you are getting, have you debugged, have you seen your list. You are adding `object.toString()` into your `List<String>`, Problem is here itself, please correct this. You might need to call getter on result or something like `result.get("themedate")` and then add to `List<String>`

Comment: But I cann't use  List<ThematicDay> result = (List<ThematicDay>) query.list(); instead of List<Object> result = (List<Object>) query.list();. When I use this
 List<ThematicDay> result = (List<ThematicDay>) query.list();
  for(ThematicDay p:result)
  {
   System.out.println("***********************"+p.getThemedate());
  }
It shows error" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.astra.model.ThematicDay "

Answer (score 0):

Below approach can be applied to iterate the hashmap with String and list of bean objects

```
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="events">
 // iterate the key here
    StringValues= ${events.key} 
 // iterate the values of list here
    <c:forEach items="${events.value}" var="item" >
        ${item} 
    </c:forEach>
 </c:forEach>
```

**See here :**

- [Example to iterate hashmap](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/iterate-hashmap-using-jstl-foreach/)

Comment: It also print value 
values of list here [Ljava.lang.Object;@1a99a72 [Ljava.lang.Object;@1dada3. Actually I need to get the result 01/14/2015 DAY100 02/14/2015 DAY107

Comment: @Priyanka Seems you are not accessing the bean properties correctly, can you update your question with code you are trying now ?

Comment: But I cann't use List<ThematicDay> result = (List<ThematicDay>) query.list()  instead of List<Object> result = (List<Object>) query.list(). Could you please explain how to store the values in list in my DaoImpl.